# Unchecking Checkboxes in Custom Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I want to unchecked my all check boxes inside listview on button click.
This my adapter class. It unchecked all check boxes but for that I have to scroll through listview.
When I scroll through it, it unchecked according to the rows that are visible.

```
public class ExpenseCalculatorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private Activity context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflator = null;
    private  ArrayList<String> data;
    private  ArrayList<String> values;
    DataBaseUtil dbUtils;


    public ExpenseCalculatorAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> data){
        super(context,R.layout.expenserow, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        dbUtils=new DataBaseUtil(context);


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String row=data.get(position);
        String date;
        String type;
        String cost;
        final String id;
        /*  result.add(c.getString(iRowid)+"&"+c.getString(iDate)+"~"+c.getString(iCost)+"#"+c.getString(iType)+"*");*/
        id=row.substring(0, row.indexOf("&"));
        date=row.substring(row.indexOf("&")+1,row.indexOf("~"));
        cost=row.substring(row.indexOf("~")+1,row.indexOf("#"));
        type=row.substring(row.indexOf("#")+1,row.indexOf("*"));

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.expenserow, null);

            holder.togCheck=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            holder.textDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtrowDate);
            holder.textType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtrowType);
            holder.textCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtrowCost);

            holder.togCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("clicked");
                    if(buttonView.isChecked())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dbUtils.open();
                            dbUtils.setVisibility(id);
                        }catch(SQLException sqx)
                        {
                            sqx.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            dbUtils.close();
                        }
                        intent.putExtra("isClicked","yes");
                        intent.putExtra("ID",""+id);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dbUtils.open();
                            dbUtils.setInVisibility(id);
                        }catch(SQLException sqx)
                        {
                            sqx.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            dbUtils.close();
                        }
                        intent.putExtra("isClicked","no");
                        intent.putExtra("ID",""+id);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

                    }
                }
            });




            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

        ViewHolder hold = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        //setting Data to List
        hold.textDate.setText(date);
        hold.textType.setText(type);
        hold.textCost.setText(cost);



        if(CheckReceiver.checkAll)
        {
            hold.togCheck.setChecked(true);


        }
        if(!CheckReceiver.checkAll)
        {
            hold.togCheck.setChecked(false);
        }


        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();



    static class ViewHolder{

        public CheckBox togCheck;
        public TextView textDate;
        public TextView textType;
        public TextView textCost;

    }

}
```

Comment: Note CheckReciver is BoradCastReciver i have set checkAll variable to true there if i pressed button to check all records in my listview. I done this cause if i use simple for loop with the condition of adapter.getCount. Some of the checkboxes have not been rendered. Or may be recycled. So it gives me Nullpointer exception. Please help me with this.. Its driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Listview recycles view its not possible to  do this with only BroadCastReciver. It was really a bad idea.
I done this using Database and BroadCastReciver.

```
holder.togCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("clicked")*/;
                    if(holder.togCheck.isChecked())
                    {
                        //holder.togCheck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
                        try
                        {
                            dbUtils.open();
                            dbUtils.setVisibility(id);
                        //  Toast.makeText(context, "Checked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }catch(SQLException sqx)
                        {
                            sqx.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            dbUtils.close();
                        }
                        intent.putExtra("isClicked","yes");
                        intent.putExtra("ID",""+id);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    //  holder.togCheck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.uncheck);

                        try
                        {
                            dbUtils.open();
                            dbUtils.setInVisibility(id);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "UnChecked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }catch(SQLException sqx)
                        {
                            sqx.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            dbUtils.close();
                        }
                        intent.putExtra("isClicked","no");
                        intent.putExtra("ID",""+id);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
```

what i done is i set the checked or unchecked state of checkbox according to id in database.
Then by fetching state of that id i done calculation!.